# why does my class only work with two constructors c++

Tags: c++, class

This does not work

When I don't have a blank constructor in my class the code will not run causing an error saying no default constructor exists for class.

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int val)
        :x(val)
    {}


private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    myClass random;
    return 0;
}
```

This works

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int val)
        :x(val)
    {}

    myClass()
    {}

private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    myClass random;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are calling wrong constructor in the first example. try `myClass random(0);`

Comment: If you call a default (no args) constructor you need to have a default (no args) constructor. The error message tells you that pretty clearly.

Comment: myClass random; you must provide a default constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you try to instantiate the object `myClass random`, you are trying to invoke the default constructor which you do not have.

If you changed it to `myClass random(3)`( basically trying to invoke the constructor that you have), you would see that the compiler would have no problems.

If you want `myClass random` to compile fine, then you must have a default constructor in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Once you declare a constructor in a `class` (any constructor), the compiler won't automatically generate a default constructor for you (this is what you're calling the blank constructor).

If you don't want to implement the default constructor (generally a good idea if you just want the default behavior), you can tell the compiler to generate it for you as of C++11.

```
class myClass {
public:
    myClass(int val)
        :x(val)
    {}

    myClass() = default; // the compiler handles the implementation

private:
    int x;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you have defined a parameterized constructor. When a constructor is defined the compiler now does not automatically define a default constructor like before.

If no constructor is defined the compiler automatically defines a default constructor but if another constructor is defined the compiler will not do so.

i.e. in first case a default constructor does not exist. In the second case you have defined one and hence has no errors.

Answer (score 0):

See [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

> If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type, the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class.

However, there's a constuctor declared in your class, thus the compiler won't declare a default constructor. You have to explicitly declare one yourself.